# UIPanRecognizer: Cant present AlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I am new to XCode and Swift...However, I thought I give it a try...I would like to have two dragable Images and if they collide an alert window should pop up...I have attached the code below... when I run the code I get the following warning:

**UIPanRecogniserSwift[10047:300286] Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting**

I am not sure how to fix this. Already tried to put the if-statement at different places in the code without success.
Also is there a possiblity to access the "reset" button in the alert window for a command (i.e. If user presses reset bring picture 1 to location x,y)?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var yellowBox: UIView!

@IBOutlet var Dice: UIImageView!



@IBAction func panYellowView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x +       translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
     self.ifCollided()


}

/*func showAlert() {
    let  alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Collided",   message: "You have collided",preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    alertController .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}*/





@IBAction func panDiceView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)


}



@IBAction func ifCollided() {

    if CGRectIntersectsRect(yellowBox.frame, Dice.frame){

        //showAlert()


            let  alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Collided", message: "You have collided",preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alertController .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            alertController .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            //showAlert()


    }

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



     //self.ifCollided()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}







override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine, you were not checking `ifCollided()` when dice is moving. This code is working fine with my `Xcode` 7.3.1 iOS 9.3

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var yellowBox: UIView!
@IBOutlet var Dice: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Dice.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panDiceView(_:))))
    yellowBox.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panYellowView(_:))))
}

func panYellowView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x +       translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    self.ifCollided()
}

func showAlert()
{
    let  alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Collided",   message: "You have collided",preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alertController .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func panDiceView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    self.ifCollided()
}

@IBAction func ifCollided()
{
    if CGRectIntersectsRect(yellowBox.frame, Dice.frame){
        showAlert()
    }
}
}
```

Try to call the method using `performSelector`

```
self.performSelector(#selector(self.showAlert))
```

Comment: hey thanks so much :) its working perfectly fine now!!

you added:

Dice.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panDiceView(_:))))
    yellowBox.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panYellowView(_:))))

under viewDidLoad. Why did you do that? cause it seems that my warnings occured because of it

Comment: If this helps please accept this as answer, and help other to find the correct solutions

Comment: I also edited the ShowAlert bit...however Im getting a warning again...could you help out again please? Not sure where to post the code bit as it is too long for a comment

Comment: What's the warning

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present Warning: Attempt to present on which is already presenting on which is already presenting

Comment: By the way what changes did you made

Comment: func ShowAlertAngry(){
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Congrats", message: " You are correct! Now RUN!!!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
     
        let okAction = UIAlertAction( title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.Angry.center = CGPointMake(150, 150)          
        }
        let resetAction = UIAlertAction( title: "Reset and hope the mood has changed", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIALertAction in
            self.Angry.center = CGPointMake(150, 150)
        }

Comment: I tried to make the alert button interactive basically

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by saying "use perform selector" tho